# NullPointerException at "new RemoteWebDriver(srvc.getUrl(), options)"

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have Three Classes as below:

And When I run the test as TestNG from 'Tests.java' I get java.lang.NullPointerException exception:

NOTE:

-It picks the browser name 'chrome' successfully from the .properties file.

-If I discard the 'Tests.java' class and move the @Test method to 'LaunchBrowserTemp.java' class and add remaining corresponding tags (i.e. BeforeClass, BeforeMethod, AfterClass, AfterMethod) to corresponding methods in 'LaunchBrowserTemp.java' it works fine. It fails only when I keep the testng annotations to the 'Tests.java' class.

**src\main\java\utilities\LaunchBrowserTemp.java**

```
    public class LaunchBrowserTemp {

          private static ChromeDriverService srvc;
          private static WebDriver driver;
          private static String browser = getProperties("selenium.browser");
          private static final String baseBrowserPath = "src\\main\\resources\\drivers\\";
          private static ChromeOptions options;

          public static void initBrowser() throws Exception {
              switch (browser.toLowerCase()){
              case "chrome":
                  options = new ChromeOptions();
                  options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
                  options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
                  options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
                  srvc = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
                        .usingDriverExecutable(new File(baseBrowserPath + "chromedriver.exe"))
                        .usingAnyFreePort()
                        .build();
                  srvc.start();
                  break;
              default:
                  throw new Exception("Browser Not handled in code!");
              }

          }

          public static void stopDriverService() {
            srvc.stop();
          }

          public void startDriver() {
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(srvc.getUrl(), options);
          }

          public void endDriver() {
            driver.quit();
          }

          public static WebDriver driver() {
              return driver;
          }

    }
```

**src\main\java\utilities\LoadProperties.java**

```
    public class LoadProperties {

        public static String getProperties(String propName) {
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            try {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/config.properties");
                prop.load(fis);
            } catch (Exception e){}
            return prop.getProperty(propName);

        }

    }
```

**src\test\java\Tests.java**

```
    public class Tests {

        LaunchBrowserTemp obj = new LaunchBrowserTemp();

        @BeforeClass
        public void init() throws Exception{
            LaunchBrowserTemp.initBrowser();
        }

        @BeforeTest
        public void start(){
            obj.startDriver();
        }

        @Test
        public void openUrl(){
            driver().get("https://www.google.com");
        }

        @AfterTest
        public void teardown(){
            obj.endDriver();
        }

        @AfterClass
        public void terminate() {
            LaunchBrowserTemp.stopDriverService();
        }

    }
```

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8v0n4.png)

Comment: Error Screenshot attached (in case if you missed): Please click on the link 'Error Screenshot' shown above.

Comment: Find out why svrc is null.

Comment: @Balamurugan  - **DO NOT** attach screenshots of error messages to your Questions.  Read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen - Thank you for your comment. After further troubleshooting I realised that srvc was never initialised. When replacedthe tag BeforeTest with BeforeMethod it worked..

Comment: @StephenC - My apologies. Point noted. Thanks.